# Network Security Tunnel

Tags: vpn, security, interface, tunnel, gre

In the Tunnel Interface, when I edit the tunnel information, it shows:

```
Attributes          Values
 Tunnel Source      IF10    
 Tunnel Destination 1.0.0.1
 Tunnel Mode         GRE
```

What does `IF10` stand for in the field for Tunnel Source? Why can `IF10` be the source for more than one tunnel?

Comment: What is the router model?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't explain what router model this is, but it is almost certain that `IF10` means `Interface 10`.

An interface can be the source for multiple tunnels because a tunnel is defined by two endpoints, and one interface is only one end.

---

FYI, GRE is not secure. You would need to use a tunnel that does encryption for a secure tunnel.